# Slide background-color over img

Tags: html, css

Here is the html markup

```
<div class="imgBox">

  <img //src="https://cdn.images.dailystar.co.uk/dynamic/122/photos/693000/900x738/1074693.jpg" alt="IMG">

  <div class="rollOver">
    lol
  </div>

</div>
```

why isn't the background-color moving from -300px to -200px when I hover over .imgBox?

css code:

```
   body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .imgBox{
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
     position: relative;
    }

    img{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;

    }
    .rollOver{
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.897);
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;  
     transform: translateX(-300px);  
     transition:all .4s ease; 

    }
```

Why doesn't it work when I hover over .imgBox, what will then happen too the .rollover

```
    .rollOver .imgBox:hover{
     transform: translateX(-200px);
     }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/61fqnyne/

Comment: Because your selector is wrong. try `.imgBox:hover rollOver ` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confess I'm not *entirely* sure on what effect you are going for but your **selector is wrong**.

You need

```
.imgBox:hover .rollOver { your styles here}
```

Something like this I imagine,

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.imgBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.rollOver {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.897);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all .4s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imgBox:hover .rollOver {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="imgBox">
  <img src="https://cdn.images.dailystar.co.uk/dynamic/122/photos/693000/900x738/1074693.jpg" alt="IMG">

  <div class="rollOver">
    lol
  </div>
</div>
```